# How do I find out what states this FSM has?

Tags: finite-automata

I have a homework assignment where I am supposed to make a visual representation of a deterministic FSM. Basically, the FSM is to accept the input string if it does **not** contain the letters a and c immediately after the other. The input alphabet `I` is `I = {a, b, c}`. As a hint, the class was told that 4 states would be enough and that three states would be endings. And here is where my problem lies: I have no idea how to know what states this machine is supposed to have. 
This is what I have come up with so far:

- States: A, B, C
- Start: A
- Input alphabet: {"a", "b", "c"}
- Endings: ?

[image: FSM first attempt]

---

I have no idea how far this is correct or if there is something that I misunderstood about making FSM visual representations. Of course I don't want the solution, but rather hints or tips to point me in the right direction.

For clarification, here are a few accepted input strings as well as input strings that will not be accepted.

Accepted strings:

- abbabcbabccb
- cbaaabccbca
- ab

Not accepted strings are:

- abcb**ca**
- abbabcbab**ac**cb

Please improve the question if possible (and add appropriate tags).

**Edit:**

This is my new attempt:

[image: diagram #3]

Comment: The goal of the exercise is for you to develop a certain skill involving automata. The only way for this goal to succeed is if you spend the time and solve the exercise on your own.

Comment: What happens when you're in state $B$ and see a $b$ as input?

Comment: @RickDecker exactly, that is a problem in the diagram of my post. I have since tried once again, here is what I came up with (please excuse my horrible paint skills, I have not yet found out how to make curved arrows with the tool I used): http://imgur.com/KvjvUOv

Comment: I couldn't get the image. Perhaps you could just tell us what happens in that case.

Comment: According to the diagram, nothing. What should happen, of course, is that we would go back to A since a b may be followed by any letter.
I can embed the image of the new diagram in my post, I will do that.

Comment: @RickDecker Please excuse the horrible paint skills in the new diagram.

Comment: You are nearly there. I suppose the word $b$ should be accepted?

Comment: $A,B,C$ should be accept states and $D$ should not be. Other than that, it looks good.